# How to custom a predefined template file?

Tags: extension, custom-templates

I want to add a button into the activity edit tab. Please refer an image.
[image]

Please provide a sample snippet (Code) for custom template

> My Snippet

```
CRM
    .$(function($) {
        console.log('Form edit ok');
        $('.action-item.crm-hover-button').click(function(){
            console.log("adding of button ok ");
        });

        $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').append('<button id="popup" name="popup">Click Here</button>');


        $("#takefeedback").click(function() {
            CRM.loadForm(CRM.url('civicrm/mypage'));
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please paste what you've already tried. This site is not for asking code snippets. You can check buildform hook https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/ to add buttons on the form.

Comment: Please refer a modified question